# Is there a filter for adding decimal for the input type?

Tags: angularjs

Need filter for adding decimals for the Input type.

```
<input type="text" class="formcontrol inputBox" ng-model="data"
       ng-pattern-restrict="^[0-9]{0,3}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$"
       id="txtamt" name="txtamt" />
```

It should automatically add decimal number when i enter some number, 
ex: if i enter 100 it should show as 100.00

Comment: Have you already looked at [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way with filter do this, but you could try something like below with directive,

```js
var app = angular.module('App',[]);
  
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {  
  
});

 app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',  
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue);
            });
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber/100,2));
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>   
  </head>

  <body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="amount" format="number" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```